# __MINGW64__ not defined? Or how do I know what threading model to use?

Tags: mingw-w64

I'm trying to resurrect the windows build of our product, but trying to move over to MingW64 for a better c++ threading experience. But, of course I don't want to just discard the old #include winpthreads code. I'd like an ifdef.

Everything I read says  **MINGW64** should be defined, but eclipse doesn't see it, nor does command-line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32>echo | bin\gcc -E -dM - | find "MING"
#define __MINGW32__ 1
```

So Is this me, or is this the way it is, or am I somehow still seeing my old mingw(32) installation?

Comment: Where did you read that **MINGW64** should be defined?

Comment: If you install mingw64 then it is defined, and I can confirm that now, but _only_ if you actually install the 64-bit version. Bizarrely, given the claims of the mingw64 fork to be better for 64bit platforms, the default is 32-bit installation, identified by the non-descriptive name 'i686'.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer.

If you install mingw64 then both `__MINGW32__` and `__MINGW64__` are defined, and I can confirm that now, but *only* if you ***actually*** install the 64-bit version.

Bizarrely, given the claims of the mingw64 fork to be better for 64bit platforms, the default is 32-bit installation, identified by the non-helpful name 'i686'. You will be wanting the 'x86_64' option instead.